# screen gui not showing up

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

im new to lua and im trying to make a roblox admin panel, but it wont work and i cant tell why

```
admins = require(script.Parent.Admins)
AdminPanel = game:FindFirstChild("ServerStorage").AdminPanel
Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    if admins[player.UserId] then
        AdminPanel:Clone().Parent = player.PlayerGui
    end
end)
```

i tried replacing the AdminPanel.Parent = player.PlayerGui with a print statement, but nothing printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to use table.find() instead

```
admins = require(script.Parent.Admins)
Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    if table.find(admins, player.UserId) then
        local AdminPanel = game:FindFirstChild("ServerStorage").AdminPanel:Clone()
        AdminPanel.Parent = player.PlayerGui
    end
end)
```

first you put in the table argument, and then the value you want to find

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?